# I can't get my intent in other ListView item because of the re-declaration of the DataSnapShot inside the for loop

Tags: java, listview, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bunch of firebase URL . And I used for loop to get data from each URL's but the problem is. The variables inside the foor loop is re declared and i'm having a problem in the Intent part because the "position" and the index is not equal

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //some code
            String[] FireBasecityURL = //SOME STRINGS 


            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++ ) {

                final String FIREBASE_URL = FireBasecityURL[x];
                Firebase firebaseRef;
                Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
                firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);


                //populate restau List
                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        int i = 0;


                        final String[] lat = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];

                       //OTHER VARIABLES



                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                                rating[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("rating").getValue().toString();
                                if (hotCTR <= Double.valueOf(rating[i])) {
                                    lat[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("lat").getValue().toString();

                                  //OTHER VARIABLES

                                    Restau.add(new restauInfoDB(resName[i], resLoc[i], R.drawable.six, resType[i], url[i], healthy[i], rating[i], cost[i]
                                            , New[i], contact[i], url1[i], url2[i], url3[i], url4[i], spec[i], oh[i]));
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }

                        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter((ArrayList<restauInfoDB>) Restau);
                        //adapter.clear();


                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


                                Intent hn = new Intent(whot.this, RestaurantView.class);

                                String positionstr = Integer.toString(position);
                                String var = menu + positionstr; //Restaurant + number of position in list view

                                String ratingURL = FIREBASE_URL + var;
                                hn.putExtra("name", resName[position]);
                                //OTHER .putExtra
                             //PROBLEM IS HERE. Position and index is not equal.
                                startActivity(hn);
                            }
                        });**
```

What is the best way for the Variables to not be re declared ?
i can't find a way to declare it outside because it is inside the valueEventListener of the FireBase

Comment: Please be more explicit; which variables shouldn't be re-declared?

Comment: the ` final String[] lat = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];`

Comment: i can't intent the other listitem because it is out of bound